# Running pre-test powershell script to change tests

Tags: c#, powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests

We have a gated check-in for our TFS Build process which is supposed to build our site to our development instance on every check-in. Our QA instance is then built nightly.  Each build triggers a series of tests, the bulk of them on the QA instance.

My test code currently runs code against the QA instance URL's and I need to change them to reflect the development URL's for the development check-ins.  I was thinking of using a powershell script to find/replace the URL's in my UIMap.Designer.cs file before each development build and change them back after the tests complete.

My question is:  Can I make changes to my .cs code files with powershell before the tests run or is that going to cause problems?  Secondly, am I taking the long way around the block or is there another way to make a coded UI test know which build it is testing?  I've looked and not been able to find any other solution thus far.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can, but if you can, I don't recommend it. I suggest to puth those urls into the configuration file and have separate configurations for the development and the QA!

Comment: You'd have to run that pre-build, no? A pre-test script runs after the build but before tests, so for a source file that is compiled into the test assembly that's too late. Also, as for CodedUI designer files, I believe the build will regenerate the designer.cs when you build so you'd have to actually edit the source uimap file. I'm not sure why you'd need to change them back afterwards. It's not like the build server checks them in.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11693645/4527057 might be what you're interested in. If you could specify the URL as part of the test settings in the build process you might have a easier time developing.